# PieChartController TestClass

Tags: apex, code-coverage, salesforce-id

I have written one piechartcontroller referring to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_overview_simple_example.htm
but I am not able to write the test class for it as I am not getting on which object I should write the query. Kindly suggest something....

```
public class PieChartController {

public PieChartController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

}

    public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() {

        List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();

        data.add(new PieWedgeData('LinkedIn', 30));

        data.add(new PieWedgeData('FaceBook', 15));

        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Twitter', 10));

        return data;

    }
    // Wrapper class

    public class PieWedgeData {

        public String name { get; set; }

        public Integer data { get; set; }

        public PieWedgeData(String name, Integer data) {

            this.name = name;

            this.data = data;

        }

    }

}
```

**Here is my test class. It's not able to save but I tried a little.**

```
@isTest
 public class PieChartController_TestClass
 {

  //SCSCHAMPS__Job__c jb=new SCSCHAMPS__Job__c();
  Job__c jb=new Job__c();

  ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(jb);
 //PieWedgeData pd=new PieWedgeData();
   {
  PieChartController ctrl = new PieChartController(sc);

 //insert pd;
Test.startTest();
//PieChartController ctrl = new PieChartController();
 PieChartController.PieWedgeData[] data = ctrl.getPieData();
 Test.stopTest();
 }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you just have an error on the controller instantiation. This is because it's expecting a standardcontroller parameter. Replace it with: `PieChartController ctrl = new PieChartController(sc);`

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems in the code. First, your controller is expecting a `standardcontroller` parameter. Second, the class `PieWedgeData` is defined inside the `PieChartController` class. So to use this type, you have to use: `PieChartController.PieWedgeData` each time:

```
public class PieChartController {

public PieChartController() {

}

    public List<PieWedgeData> getPieData() {

        List<PieWedgeData> data = new List<PieWedgeData>();

        data.add(new PieWedgeData('LinkedIn', 30));

        data.add(new PieWedgeData('FaceBook', 15));

        data.add(new PieWedgeData('Twitter', 10));

        return data;

    }
    // Wrapper class

    public class PieWedgeData {

        public String name { get; set; }

        public Integer data { get; set; }

        public PieWedgeData(String name, Integer data) {

            this.name = name;

            this.data = data;

        }

    }

}
```

**Test class**

```
@isTest
public class PieChartController_TestClass
{
   @IsTest static void testMain(){
      Job__c jb=new Job__c();
      PieChartController.PieWedgeData pd=new PieChartController.PieWedgeData('facebook', 20);
      Test.startTest();
      PieChartController ctrl = new PieChartController();
      PieChartController.PieWedgeData[] data = ctrl.getPieData();
      Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55359/discussion-on-answer-by-martin-lezer-piechartcontroller-testclass).